Opentelemetry context propagation in nestjs app
there. I bumped into a problem with configuration of OTEL for NestJS. I want to add additional information into the span attributes and propagate it over all trace. I use baggage. My entry point is nest interceptor.
@Injectable()
export class TracingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {

    intercept(reqContext: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        const oldContext = context.active()
        const tracer = trace.getTracer('controller-tracer');
        const currentBaggage = propagation.getBaggage(oldContext) ?? propagation.createBaggage();
        // Add entries to baggage
        const updatedBaggage = currentBaggage
            .setEntry('custom', {
                value: 'my value',
            })

        // Set the updated baggage in context
        const baggageContext = propagation.setBaggage(context.active(), updatedBaggage);

        // Start a new span with the baggage context
        const span = tracer.startSpan(
            'Tracing: add auth entity',
            { kind: SpanKind.SERVER },
            baggageContext,
        );

        const newContext = trace.setSpan(baggageContext, span);

        return context.with(newContext, () => {
            return next.handle().pipe(
                tap({
                    next: () => {
                        span.setStatus({ code: SpanStatusCode.OK });
                        span.end();
                    },
                    error: (error) => {
                        span.recordException(error);
                        span.setStatus({ code: SpanStatusCode.ERROR, message: error.message });
                        span.end();
                    }
                }),
            )
        });
    }
}

My problem is - I can create span with my custom baggage attributes but new context is spred on Observable object only. All data in stream are emitted with older/previous context.
And my trace tree looks like: 
But I need that spans Tracing: get stat and GET were children for Tracing: add auth entity. Not siblings.

It's not possible in the interceptor. Better to use NestMiddleware.
